# Avoid errors while copying a file and another process writes to it

Tags: c#, .net, windows

i am writing a simple folder synchronization app.

Therefore i want at the time a file is created in the source folder it should be
copied to the destination.

My question is : how can i avoid errors when trying to read the source file, since another process might want to write to it ? Should i read the file in Read Write Share mode or is a simple System.IO.File.Copy enough ?

Thanks !

Comment: Do you want to block writers or do you want to allow them?  If the latter, do you want to see their changes or not?

Comment: I want to allow writers. I do not mind if the Copy process fails but the write process should not fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**File Copy** will lock the file while it is being copied.
If it wasn't locked, the file could be corrupted during the copy by another process
So, when you start the copy process there are two possibilities:

- None has a lock on your source file, then File.Copy start its work
  and locks the source file.
- Someone has a lock on your source file, then File.Copy will throw an
  exception.